# How to change the path of URL in yii

Tags: yii

I have a question about yii URL.

For example, `http://localhost/example/index.php?r=site/login`, how could I change it to `http://localhost/example/login`?

I am able to change it to `http://localhost/example/index.php/login` by editing `protected/config/main.php`.

Below is my urlManager setting.

```
'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false, //<-added as suggested by Martin
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/view',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            'login' => 'site/login',
        ),
    ),
```

My question is how can I remove(hiding) the '**index.php**' in `http://localhost/example/index.php/login` ?

**SOLVED**
I move .htaccess file from inside `protected` to root directory, where `index.php` is.

```
www
- protected
- index.php
- .htaccess
```

Can refer to http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/214/url-hide-index-php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add “'showScriptName' => false,” to the rules array.

Comment: Martin Merfort, I had editted my question. But still it cant works. Do I miss out anything?